# Editando arquivo com links em shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

Tenho um arquivo com 130 links para fazer downloads via `wget`, todos os arquivos estão com os links enumerados tal como:

```
http://minhateca.com.br/Animesdojonny/Desenhos/THUNDERCATS/Thundercats+-+Completo/Thundercats-EP001,743727846.rar
http://minhateca.com.br/Animesdojonny/Desenhos/THUNDERCATS/Thundercats+-+Completo/Thundercats-EP002,743718235.rar
http://minhateca.com.br/Animesdojonny/Desenhos/THUNDERCATS/Thundercats+-+Completo/Thundercats-EP003,743703720.rar
```

porem tenho que editar o arquivo em que se encontram estes links e deixá-los assim:

```
#Thundercats-EP001.rar
#http://minhateca.com.br/Animesdojonny/Desenhos/THUNDERCATS/Thundercats+-+Completo/Thundercats-EP001,743727846.rar
wget -O Thundercats-EP001.rar "http://s8580.minhateca.com.br/File.aspx?e=B80c6ks-HZZR2HnE2P_Qj0fY-7MZkLDpI14Qrtckc2t05nqVSDeWdt9kcRhuVHjt_FcwOfwZWuehkAwz613_Df_nzlazlznNiZD2vqM-PO0ST7b3hOVRZD_8WmGTRL3OKB3FEbcAqy5_olQ5syvbgA&pv=2"
unrar e Thundercats-EP001.rar


#Thundercats-EP002.rar
#http://minhateca.com.br/Animesdojonny/Desenhos/THUNDERCATS/Thundercats+-+Completo/Thundercats-EP002,743718235.rar
wget -O Thundercats-EP002.rar "http://s8562.minhateca.com.br/File.aspx?e=aoEnt8uY-4ccqVF8bEQ7dbdJcsgPlkKl8zLQUXjU-WZzX-PJlAOxeNOvuRDm-9MNxnRB3_9psA36wqfRAycHXgldFGoxz_xaENafIQ6t_yhtWLYgyeh-5nHQdyht6tFxb-mOJBFXvaBfgu5L0zK12A&pv=2"
unrar e Thundercats-EP002.rar


#Thundercats-EP003.rar
#http://minhateca.com.br/Animesdojonny/Desenhos/THUNDERCATS/Thundercats+-+Completo/Thundercats-EP003,743703720.rar
wget -O Thundercats-EP003.rar "http://s8581.minhateca.com.br/File.aspx?e=K218wb9_yo9qMQ9KU174NRrct9sJ_Kg-Y27HmaoOGAmCsFRDMzz0GnAu8zso-EzVYxKTYM2w1Fh7-m1eyCmFzf2RWQzzdc4ZguCKj72cV0xt3RxggUicqrUotOBzbxr5P4EXUpsPSdgT6lhkL1XmbA&pv=2"
unrar e Thundercats-EP003.rar
```

então fiz um programa que edita isso mas ele ao invés de enumerar seguidamente, ele esta editando da seguinte forma abaixo:

```
#Thundercats-EP001.rar
#http://minhateca.com.br/Animesdojonny/Desenhos/THUNDERCATS/Thundercats+-+Completo/Thundercats-EP001,743727846.rar
wget -O Thundercats-EP001.rar ""
unrar e Thundercats-EP001.rar


#Thundercats-EP001.rar
#http://minhateca.com.br/Animesdojonny/Desenhos/THUNDERCATS/Thundercats+-+Completo/Thundercats-EP002,743718235.rar
wget -O Thundercats-EP001.rar ""
unrar e Thundercats-EP001.rar


#Thundercats-EP001.rar
#http://minhateca.com.br/Animesdojonny/Desenhos/THUNDERCATS/Thundercats+-+Completo/Thundercats-EP003,743703720.rar
wget -O Thundercats-EP001.rar ""
unrar e Thundercats-EP001.rar
```

quando deveria editar assim:

```
#Thundercats-EP001.rar
#http://minhateca.com.br/Animesdojonny/Desenhos/THUNDERCATS/Thundercats+-+Completo/Thundercats-EP001,743727846.rar
wget -O Thundercats-EP001.rar ""
unrar e Thundercats-EP001.rar


#Thundercats-EP002.rar
#http://minhateca.com.br/Animesdojonny/Desenhos/THUNDERCATS/Thundercats+-+Completo/Thundercats-EP002,743718235.rar
wget -O Thundercats-EP002.rar ""
unrar e Thundercats-EP002.rar


#Thundercats-EP003.rar
#http://minhateca.com.br/Animesdojonny/Desenhos/THUNDERCATS/Thundercats+-+Completo/Thundercats-EP003,743703720.rar
wget -O Thundercats-EP003.rar ""
unrar e Thundercats-EP003.rar
```

o programa é este abaixo:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOCATES=${LOCATES:-$(find . -name "downloads")}

ALL_NAMES=${ALL_NAMES:-$(cat ${LOCATES} | cut -f8 -d /)}
ALL_LINKS=${ALL_LINKS:-$(cat ${LOCATES})}

VEC_NAMES=(${ALL_NAMES})
VEC_LINKS=(${ALL_LINKS})

echo ""
for ((l = 1; l <= ${#VEC_NAMES[@]}; l++))
do
NAMES=$(printf "%s%03u.%s" "${ALL_NAMES:0:14}" ${l} "${ALL_NAMES:28:3}")

sed -i 's/^/#'${NAMES}'\n#/g;s/$/\nwget -O '${NAMES}' '\"\"'\nunrar e '${NAMES}'\n\n/g;' ${LOCATES}

done #fim primeiro for
```

qual é o meu erro?

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN { FS="/" } { split($8, a, ","); printf "#%s.rar\n#%s\nwget -O %s.rar \"%s\"\nunrar -e %s.rar\n\n", a[1], $0, a[1], $0, a[1] }' < arquivo.txt`

Comment: este comando deu certo valeu pela ajuda...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uma maneira mais simples seria:

```
awk  -i inplace -F "[/,]"  '{print 
 $8".rar"}' links.txt

cat links.txt
```

> Thundercats-EP001.rar
>
> Thundercats-EP002.rar
>
> Thundercats-EP003.rar